# php & nodejs (под задачи, личное мнение)

Tags: php, node.js

Здравствуйте, изучаю php уже пол года, создавал пару сайтов, но всегда меня заносило на создание динамический сайтов, использую для этого ajax + php. Так вот, есть ли смысл использовать ajax + php + сокеты, для более чем real time сайта и как он будет работать при сильных нагрузках или лучше же использовать nodejs?

Можно, пожалуйста, развернутые ответы.

Comment: Вам никто на этот вопрос не ответит. Что такое сильные нагрузки? 1000 посетителей? Миллион? Две калеки в обед? Что у вас в бд - две таблицы или 300? Что у вас на сервере - дряхлое железо или свеженькие SSD? И так далее.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2):

Вы не понимаете архитектуры действительно высоких нагрузок.

Совершенно неважно, что за ПО вы используете на сервере. Допустим, при использовании PHP вы сможете выжать произоводительность в 1000 пользователей, при использовании ноды - 2000 пользователей, при использовании ассемблера - 3000.

Так вот хайлоад -- это не про то, что нужно срочно переходить на ассемблер, а про то, что любой используемый стек технологий гарантировнно заткнётся на миллионах пользователей (крупные соц.сети, сайты поисковиков).

Поэтому начинают архитектурно придумывать приёмы, как поставить стопятьсот серверов, чтобы их хватило для обработки нагрузки.

Способов много (слышали например такое слово, как "шардинг"?), архитектуру можно приложить и к ноде и к PHP.

Выбор стека делается при старте проекта часто по историческим причинам. Скажем, собрались несколько c# программистов - и стали писать stackoverflow на .net, а пришла Цукербергу в голову идея писать фейсбук -- выбрал PHP, потому что умел или показалось проще. На чём умели -- на том и стартанули.

Резкая смена стека в середине проекта, когда у вас сотни серверов и десятки программистов, знающих этот стек -- это редкая и безумная вещь. Ну выгадаете двадцать серверов -- на сотне серверов это может оказаться экономией на спичках по сравнению с тем, что вам нужно уволить всех программистов, нанять новых и всё это без простоя. Бизнес это не одобрит.

Больше по вопросу сказать нечего. Он очень неконкретный и на него сложно дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Ну что же Вы так? Язык влияет на время и возможности. Хотя сильно зависит от архитектуры, согласен.

Comment: Ничего безумного в смене стека нет, можно несколько одновременно гонять. К примеру, есть у меня сервис на perl, всё работает, только вот последний perl программист остался. Уйдёт в любой момент. Переписываем сервис на чём-либо другом, и переходим по частям, нода за нодой.. Язык - не священная корова.

Comment: @vp_arth В постепенной -- нет, в резкой -- есть. И чем постепеннее -- тем больше стоимость перехода, бизнесу это тем больше не понравится. Я не против вашего замечания, а полностью согласен: просто для ответа мне нужно было заострить формулировки, чтобы было понятнее спрашивающему, а у вас, как комментирующего,  другая задача: показать, что нет ничего однозначного и нужно в каждом конкретном случае смотреть по обстоятельствам.