# Совместая работа nodeJS и PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, node.js, сокет, события

Хотелось бы выяснить мнение про в этом вопросе: есть ли смысл строить связку `PHP` + `nodeJS(sockets)`, и если да, то как сделать это лучше всего? Например, при апдейтах БД в `PHP` - оповещать `JS` об этом и хэндлить там событие.
*Из личных соображений - только подписка на события к какому-нибудь редису, либо с пхп ваять запросы сокет-вида на порт к JS, но это тот еще костыль.*
Либо, лучше просто вести разработку внутри одной среды `JS/PHP`? (емнип сокеты на пхп, не самая удобная штука, зато с базой общаться там куда привычнее и проще)

Comment: *зато с базой общаться там куда удобнее и проще* -- спорно.

Comment: @D-side, да, наверное тут уместнее `привычнее`. Fix'd

Comment: У нас вопросы вида "есть ли смысл" обычно закрывают, т. к. в зависимости от большого количества параметров из обстоятельств ответ может быть "да" и "нет", и покрывать все сценарии вряд ли кто-то возьмётся. А вот из предположения, что вы **хотите** так сделать, можете спросить о том, **как**. Причём по возможности поконкретнее, изложив желаемую структуру. И увидев ответы, примете для себя решение, есть смысл или нет.

Comment: Скажем, [вот пример довольно похожего вопроса, хотя и немного про другое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622690/php-nodejs-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?rq=1).

Comment: @D-side, ну помимо общего вопроса был поставлен весьма конкретный, "как дергать ноду через пхп", его все упорно игнорируют кидаются минусами и разочарованно вздыхают. Кто-то добавил этот вопрос в избранное, значит он имеет место быть уже как минимум для двух человек. Это вопрос не с абстрактным ответом, а с вполне конкретным, как связать между собой 2 технологии, и есть ло в этом смысл. Если тут спросят, как скопировать файл в пхп, вы ведь не будете рассуждать о целях, просто дадите ответ. Это не вопрос лучше/хуже, скорее желание увидеть бест практис

Comment: *Кто-то добавил этот вопрос в избранное* -- ну, уже нет. А если вы хотите, чтобы люди не обращали внимание на этот общий вопрос и не тянулись к минусам и закрывашкам, уберите его из вопроса вообще, например.

Comment: @D-side, я хочу, чтобы люди проявляли меньше снобизма и больше лояльности вопросам. Это не сравнение ЦМС для бложика, и не вопрос - какую ось на сервер поставить, хотя даже в этих случаях можно было достаточно конкретно расписать +/- тех или иных вариантов. Так же и тут, мне хочется получить совет, стоит ли так делать, не стоит, или есть вариант лучше, или я вообще двигаюсь не в том направлении. Увы, ресурса с советами я не знаю, но не считаю, что подобный вопрос, ожидающий ответы с бест практисами - это плохо. На гугление выпало много нерелевантщины типа "нода против пхп".

Answer (score 3):

Понимаете, чем более единообразный набор для разработки, тем **удобнее на нем писать и поддерживать проект**.

Набор технологий зависит от зависит от требований к скорости, качеству, умений команды и т.д. Используя различные языки на одном уровне, вы усложняете себе разработку, следовательно дорожает поддержка бизнес-процессов.

Представьте, **вы один разработчик**, на backend у вас javascript (nodejs) для работы с веб-сокетами, php для api, erlang для демонов, java для микросервисных модулей, на front у вас половина на javascript, а половина на typescript.

Да это работает, но случись какая-нибудь специфичная ошибка, сколько времени вы потратите на поиск ответа? Врятли вы знаете тонкости всего стека.

В разных языках, действительно что-то реализовывать удобнее, чем в других языках, но следует оценивать какую выгоду вы получите от этого и как это повлияет на дальнейшую разработку? Если особой выгоды нет, просто поищите библиотеки с удобными интерфейсами для реализации вашего функционала или выбирайте язык, который для ваших нужд устраивает больше всего.